# Question about VertexTextureCoordinates

Tags: graphics, textures

Background: consider the following snippet:

```
 gp := Graphics
 bill = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyojA.jpg"];
 poly1 = {{1, 0}, {.5, .86}, {-.5, .86}, {-1, 0}, {-.5, -.86}, {.5, -.86}};
 g1 = {Texture[bill], Polygon[poly1, VertexTextureCoordinates -> poly1]};
 poly2 = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
 g2 = {Texture[bill], Polygon[poly2, VertexTextureCoordinates -> poly2]};
 g1 // gp
 g2 // gp
```

[image: example of output]

The option `VertexTextureCoordinates` isn't entirely clear to me. I want to put an image with the correct ratios in the hexagon left. So for example on {{-.5,-.5},{.5,-.5},{.5,5},{-.5,.5}}. (I have not been able to get this to work although I have tried all sort of possibilities) However with the restriction that if I rescale the (coordinates of the) hexagon the image should be scaled accordingly.

EDIT-1:
 [image]
Image as requested.

EDIT-2:
This nicely sums up and demonstrates the answer by Heike:

```
 rescale1[poly_, p1_, p2_] := 
  Transpose[{Rescale[poly[[All, 1]], {p1[[1]], p2[[1]]}, {0, 1}], 
    Rescale[poly[[All, 2]], {p1[[2]], p2[[2]]}, {0, 1}]}]
 Manipulate[
  g = {Texture[bill], 
     Polygon[poly, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> rescale1[poly, leftbot, righttop]]} //
     Graphics,
  {leftbot, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {righttop, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
  Initialization :> {righttop = {1, 1}}, ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

Key is the mapping between the image and vertextexture coordinates.

Comment: Could you please use an image that is available to anyone, e.g. `ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]`? Otherwise good question.

Comment: Yes, you can use that image as well. Doesn't really matter.

Comment: Yes, of course it does not matter, it is simply easier for everyone else to copy & run your example without having to manually edit it.

Comment: Point taken @IstvánZachar

Comment: @ndroock: You could... I don't know, upload the image you have (`captain-bill.jpg`) using the built-in image uploader, and then everybody else can execute `Import[(* URL for captain-bill.jpg *)]`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a generalisation of kguler and Verbeia's answers, you could do something like this

```
rescale[poly_] :=
  Module[{xrange, yrange, ratio, midp},
   xrange = Through[{Min, Max}[poly[[All, 1]]]];
   yrange = Through[{Min, Max}[poly[[All, 2]]]];
   midp = {Total[xrange], Total[yrange]}/2;
   Rescale[(# - midp) & /@ poly, 
    Max[yrange[[2]] - yrange[[1]], xrange[[2]] - xrange[[1]]]/2 {-1, 1}, {0, 1}]
   ];

Graphics[{Texture[bill], Polygon[poly1, VertexTextureCoordinates -> rescale[poly1]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`rescale` is basically doing the same thing as the line `Rescale[poly1,{-1,1},{0,1}]` in the answers above except that the range over which to rescale is calculated automatically. This means that you can use it to rescale the vertex coordinates of any polygon without having to figure out the minimum and maximum values of the coordinates first, e.g.

```
SeedRandom[];
poly3 = (2 # + BlockRandom[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2]]) & /@ poly1;
Graphics[{Texture[bill], 
  Polygon[poly1, VertexTextureCoordinates -> rescale[poly1]],
  Polygon[poly3, VertexTextureCoordinates -> rescale[poly3]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Concerning your comment, in the coordinate system used for specifying `VertexTextureCoordinates`, `{0, 0}` corresponds to the lower left corner of the image used for the texture and `{1, 1}` to the upper right corner. This coordinate system is cyclic with period 1 which means that for example the point `{2.3, -0.8}` corresponds to the same point in the image as the points `{0.3, 0.2}`. To align the texture with the polygon such that the points `p1` and `p2` (in the coordinate system of the polygon) correspond to the lower left and upper right corners of the image, you need to rescale the coordinates of the vertices of the polygon so that `p1` will be mapped to `{0, 0}` and `p2` to `{1, 1}`, for example by doing something like

```
rescale1[poly_, p1_, p2_] := Transpose[{Rescale[poly[[All, 1]], {p1[[1]], p2[[1]]}, {0, 1}],
  Rescale[poly[[All, 2]], {p1[[2]], p2[[2]]}, {0, 1}]}]

Graphics[{Texture[bill], 
  Polygon[poly1, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> rescale1[poly1, {-.5, -.5}, {.5, .5}]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here I've chosen `p1 == {-.5, -.5}` and `p2 == {.5, .5}` which will centre the texture.

Comment: How do the VertexTextureCoordinates exactly relate to the coordinates of the image? I want to put the bottom left point of the image to the bottom left vertex of the hexagon. Leave the ratio intact. Tile from there. - If that's possible of course.

Comment: @ndroock1 I've updated my answer

Comment: Per request in the Meta section I wait at least 24h with my accept. Once again great help.

Comment: Your rescale1 function and explanation deserve a place in the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

kguler's answer is perfectly correct but I thought it worth mentioning that rescaling the `Polygon` itself is not necessary, only the vertices:

```
gp := Graphics
bill = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

rawpoly = {{1, 0}, {.5, .86}, {-.5, .86}, {-1, 
    0}, {-.5, -.86}, {.5, -.86}};

poly1 = Rescale[rawpoly, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}];
g1 = {Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]], 
   Polygon[rawpoly, VertexTextureCoordinates -> poly1]};

g1 // gp
```

[image]

The important point is that, regardless of the coordinates of the enclosing graphic, the `VertexTextureCoordinates` fall in a naturally rescaled unit square (`{0,0}` to `{1,1}`), and if the coordinates in this option fall outside this region, you end up with multiple tiles of the graphic, as seen in your question. If on the other hand, you rescale to a range that is smaller than the unit square, you will only show a portion of the picture but you can center the picture somewhere else in the graphic. Notice how the picture is displaced here relative to the first version.

```
rawpoly = {{1, 0}, {.5, .86}, {-.5, .86}, {-1, 
    0}, {-.5, -.86}, {.5, -.86}};

poly1 = Rescale[{{1, 0}, {.5, .86}, {-.5, .86}, {-1, 
     0}, {-.5, -.86}, {.5, -.86}}, {-0.5, 0.9}, {0.4, 1}];
g2 = {Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]], 
   Polygon[rawpoly, VertexTextureCoordinates -> poly1]};
g2 // gp
```

[image]

Just for fun, proof that it was the scaling of the vertices, not the ordering, that was the issue:

```
g2 = {Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]], 
   Polygon[rawpoly, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> RotateRight[poly1, 2]]};
```

[image]

Comment: This already helps but I want it on {{-.5,-.5},{.5,-.5},{.5,5},{-.5,.5}} in the hexagon. Or any set of coordinates for that matter. I still don't get it how the option works.

Comment: Ok. I am now so far that I understand that the key lies in the right application of Rescale. The doc is rather thin on that function. A lot of trial- and error-ing required I suppose.

Comment: good point. (+1) @ndroock1, I too am unclear about  "on {{-.5,-.5},{.5,-.5},{.5,5},{-.5,.5}} in the hexagon"; perhaps a textured rectangle inside a hexagon?

Comment: @kugler The example, clearly, isn't of a major importance. I do want to understand the VertexTextureCoordinates. I read the docs of course, but they are not clear to me. I want to map imported pics to tilings.

Comment: in the docs it says:Texture[obj] is equivalent to Texture[Rasterize[obj]] and will rasterize obj at the size and resolution it would normally be displayed in a notebook. The texture is rasterized before fit to the shape. You can adjust it.

Answer (score 6):

Does this work?

```
lena=ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
poly1 = {{1, 0}, {.5, .86}, {-.5, .86}, {-1, 0}, {-.5, -.86}, {.5, -.86}};
scldpoly1=Rescale[poly1,{-1,1},{0,1}];
g1 = {Texture[lena],Polygon[scldpoly1,VertexTextureCoordinates -> scldpoly1]};

Graphics[g1]
```

[image]

or something like:

```
poly2 = {{-.5, -.5}, {.5, -.5}, {.5, .5}, {-.5, .5}}; 
Graphics[{Brown, Polygon[poly1], Texture[lena], 
Polygon[poly2, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT 3: For centered tiling** shifting the polygon corrdinates by .5 does the centered tiling without having to use `Rescale`:

```
poly1X = poly1 - .5;
g1 = {Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]], 
Polygon[poly1, VertexTextureCoordinates -> poly1X]};
```

[image]

```
Row[Graphics[{Texture[lena],Polygon[poly1, VertexTextureCoordinates -> # poly1X]}] & /@ Range[2, 5]]
```

[image]

Comment: This already helps but I want it on  {{-.5,-.5},{.5,-.5},{.5,5},{-.5,.5}} in the hexagon.

Comment: @ndroock1 I don't understand what you are trying to get - do you want a single copy of the picture, centered on that coordinate? In that case, you need `Inset`. I can do up another answer if that's what you wanted.

Comment: I want to know how the function works, basically. But to be specific about the case I submitted. No not a single copy. I want it tiled with the initial copy at the given coordinates.

Comment: @ndroock1, thanks... now I see..